# Deploying website to Azure: Database Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I've developed a website which I wanna host on Azure, and the website includes a Database for which I use Entity Framework 6.

In the Azure control panel, under the SQL Databases node, I have hosted the db and when I run my website on locallhost, the database is successfully connected and the application works very well.

When I publish my website using VS web Deploy (in the Azure's control pannels Website node), I see the following error indicating that there is a DB connection problem :

```
Cannot open database "WebApplication11050_db" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Test'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '181fabe7-aedd-4423-a29d-61ae439d9520'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.
```

That's all the configurations I have in Azure, which is One DB and one Hosted Website.

One more thing I'd like to mention is that although it says "Cannot open database WebApplication11050_db", **I do not have any DB by that name at all** and my db is named "AirLine". My connection string is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AirLineEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database.csdl|res://*/Models.Database.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=a6v0245cs5.database.windows.net;initial catalog=AirLine;user id=Test;password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm not very familiar with this azure thing, I'd appracite any help on how to fix this.

Comment: The username in the connection string for your azure database will look like `user@a6v0245cs5`.

Comment: @KeithPayne: isn't that the server name "User@a6v0245cs5.database.windows.net"

Comment: @KeithPayne: That did not solve the problem.

Comment: Well, user is not the real name. Sorry for not being clear with that. Replace `user` with what you set up when you created the azure database.

Comment: @KeithPayne: Of course I know that, the problem is not related to the user ID because it works on locallhost as I said

Comment: @KeithPayne: This Db "WebApplication11050_db", the problem is that I don't have that DB, and what is that ?

Comment: There's a login that you chose when you created the azure database. It would have no connection to your local database config.

Comment: @KeithPayne: I haven't chosen anything like that, I authenticate users using my own DB, no Active Directory login for this website

Comment: This isn't about authenticating your users. You have to get access to SQL Azure for your web application first. This will fix it all up: Go to manage.windowsazure.com, select your database from the all items list, on the bottom right there is a section titled "quick glance". One of the items in there is "show connection strings". You'll see the one for ADO.NET in there.

Comment: @KeithPayne: No, I figured it out, the format for the DB name is apparently forced to be "WebsiteName_db" when the site is deployed, it seems that Azure automatically changes that!

Comment: @KeithPayne: So I renamed the db to "WebApplication11050_db" and the problem was solved!

Comment: You should write that as an answer and mark it as such so that other users searching will see it.

Comment: Can you reach the server from your IP? If no, add your IP in the server console on Azure